# How does Constrained Nonlinear Optimization VI works? (Theory)

Tags: labview

I am trying to get the theory behind LabVIEW's [Constrained Nonlinear Optimization VI](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/gmath/constrained_nonlinear_optimization/). There description provides how to use it but not which optimization algorithms works behind it.
Here is an overview of the [optimization algorithms](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/gmath/optimization_vis/) but it simply states

> Solves a general nonlinear optimization problem with nonlinear equality constraint and nonlinear inequality constraint bounds using a sequential quadratic programming method.

[image: Constrained Nonlinear Optimization VI]

I suspect that it is a wrapper for multiple algorithms depending on the inputs... I want to know if it uses a  *Levenberg-Marquardt* or a *Downhill-Simplex* or other theory. It is not even said if it is *trust-region* or *line search* and how the bounds are ensured (e.g. by reflection)... In other languages, the documentation often refers to a paper from which I can take the original theory. This is what I am looking for. Can anyone help (or do I have to contact the NI support)? Thx

(using LabVIEW 2017 and 2018 32bit)

Comment: `using a sequential quadratic programming method` - have you searched for description of this method? Maybe it will answer your concerns?

Comment: fair enough. I was hoping for a hint, which implementation of SQP was used.... and I had the abreviation NLD buzzing around in my head for the Constrained Ninlinear Optimization VI